# Pythonのbottleモジュールについて

Tags: python, bottle

Pythonについて。

只今、『入門 Python3』を読んでPythonを学んでいます。
OSはwindows10です。 
それでは質問です。

『9.2.4 Bottle』より。

まず、ポート番号9999というテストウェブサーバーを実行しました。
そして、bottle1.pyというファイルに、
以下のコードを保存しました。

```
from bottle import route, run
@route('/')
def home() :
    return "It isn't fancy, but it's my home page"

run(host = 'localhost', port = 9999)
```

これは、ブラウザで`http://localhost:9999`にアクセスしたときに、
"It isn't fancy, but it's my home page"と表示させるものです。

そして、

```sh
$ python bottle1.py
```

と入力し、このサーバースクリプトを実行した上で
アクセスすると、ブラウザ上では表示されるようでした。

私はこれを実行せずにアクセスし、それでも表示されたので不思議に思いましたが、
先に進めば分かるかもと思い、次のステップに進みました。

今度は、

```html
My <b>new</b> and <i>improved</i> home page!!!
```

という一行が書かれたhtmlファイルと、

```
from bottle import route, run, static_file
@route('/')
def main() :
return static_file('index.html', root = '.')
run(host = 'localhost', port = 9999)
```

というコードが書かれたbottle2.pyという名前のファイルを作り、
実行しました。

しかし、サーバーを再起動したりサーバースクリプトを実行したにも関わらず、
表示されたのは
It isn't fancy, but it's my home page
でした。

1. 最初にbottle1.pyを実行せずにサーバーにアクセスしたときに、なぜ、一見正しく表示することが出来たのでしょう？
2. bottle2.pyを実行したのに、なぜ、『My new and improved home page!!!』が表示されないのでしょう？

長文でしたが、最後まで読んでいただきありがとうございました。

Comment: ここで同じことをやってる人が居るようなので、それをなぞって確かめてみたらどうでしょう？ [\[Python3 入門 20日目\]9章 ウェブを解きほぐす（9.1〜9.4）](https://qiita.com/Taka20200105/items/9286239742403510abd5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. 最初にbottle1.pyを実行せずにサーバーにアクセスしたときに、なぜ、一見正しく表示することが出来たのでしょう？
>      の回答です。

**過去最低１回は、ブラウザでhttp://localhost:9999にアクセスしたときのキャッシュが残っていた。(推測です)**

```
python bottle1.py
```

を実行せずに、ブラウザで`http://localhost:9999`にアクセスしたときに、
`"It isn't fancy, but it's my home page"`と表示されたのですね。

それまで１回も`python bottle1.py`を実行せずに、この文言がブラウザに表示されることは考え難いので(偶然の一致が過ぎる)、おそらく１回は`python bottle1.py`を実行したものと推測します。

となると、以下のケースが考えられます。
1)過去実行した`python bottle1.py`が生きていた
2)ブラウザのキャッシュに残っていた
サーバの再起動でも表示されるとなると「ブラウザのキャッシュに残っていた」ことが有力です。

ChromeやLynxで試してみましたが現象を再現できませんでした。原因は別にあるかもしれません。

---

---

> 2. bottle2.pyを実行したのに、なぜ、『My new and improved home page!!!』が表示されないのでしょう？

**コードにエラーがあり、表示されない**

```
from bottle import route, run, static_file
@route('/')
def main() :
return static_file('index.html', root = '.')
run(host = 'localhost', port = 9999)
```

を実行すると次のエラーが発生します。

```
  File "bottle2.py", line 4
    return static_file('index.html', root = '.')
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

こちらの環境で、インデントを正した`bottle2.py`を実行したところ、'index.html'の内容が表示されました。

```
from bottle import route, run, static_file
@route('/')
def main() :
    return static_file('index.html', root = '.')
run(host = 'localhost', port = 9999)
```

Comment: 申し訳ありません。インデントは正しく出来ておりましたがこちらの記述ではインデントが無効になっていたようでした。
キャッシュの削除をしてからサーバーの再起動をしてみました。
何度やっても、
ファイルが存在しませんというエラーが出ました。

しかし、今しがた、エクスプローラーからファイルの実行をしてみたら、
My new～が表示できました。